# How to access the user object in the form configure method

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm currently doing this kind fo thing with symfony forms

```
$this->myForm = new MyForm();
$this->myForm->customConfigureMethod($this->getUser()->getGuardUser());
```

because I need to configure a DoctriineChoice widget on the basis of the user.

I would rather do this kind of thing

```
$this->myForm =new myCustomConfiguredForm($this->getUser()->getGuardUser());
```

With the customisation being part of the form instantiation.

Anyone know how I could achieve this? I think I might be a bit unclear about the difference between the configure() and setup() functions for the forms so can't think clearly about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shpuld pass the user object as an option. Here is an exapmle:

```
class ProductForm extends BaseProductForm
{
  public function configure()
  { 
    // or use an instance variable if you need the user in an another method too
    $user = $this->getOption('user');

    if (!$user instanceof sfBasicSecurityUser)
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('A user object is required as "user" option in ' . __METHOD__);
    }

    // do something with the user...
  }

}

$form = new ProductForm(array(), array('user' => $this->getUser()));
```