# accessing session variable in ClassGeneratorConfiguration in symfony1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

Is there any way to access session variable from ClassGeneratorConfiguration in symfony1.4?
I need it because i want to set default filter field values according to session variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from the context (I think there is no other way) and than you can use the `getFilterDefaults` method to set a default value for a field or use the `getFilterFormOptions` to [pass the user into the form as an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276398/how-to-access-the-user-object-in-the-form-configure-method) and implement the logic there. This is how I usally do it:

```
class productGeneratorConfiguration extends BaseProductGeneratorConfiguration
{
  /**
   * @return sfBasicSecurityUser
   */
  public function getUser()
  {
    return sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
  }

  public function getFilterFormOptions()
  {
    return array('user' => $this->getUser());
  }

  public function getFilterDefaults()
  {
    return array(
      'some_field' => $this->getUser()->getSomething() ? 'a' : 'b';
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access session variable like follows:

$varname = sfContext::getInstance->getUser()->getAttribute('your_field');